# XSLT in a loop keep getting only first file transformation in the output. How to Stop caching XSLT output

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, xslt-1.0

When I am looping thru list of files and doing transformation on each file in a folder the effect of the transformation is as if it keeps transforming first file again and again. The transformation looked to be caching. 
Here is the Code for transformation: 
I am doing this inside WebAPI call.. in .NET framework 4.5.2 version . The ASP.NET page is calling the WebAPI.

I tried all different overloads and moving instancing transformation new out of loop on the top. I did not find any easy way of disabling the caching.

```
       var d = new DirectoryInfo(strXMLFolder);
            foreach (FileInfo file in d.GetFiles())
            {
                 String strXSLTFile = strParamArr[2];
                String xmlFile = file.Name;
                //File.WriteAllBytes(strFile, transferObj.XSLTTemplateFileData);
                XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
                proc.Load(strXSLTFolder + strXSLTFile);
                proc.Transform(strXMLFolder + xmlFile, strXMLFolder + xmlFile + "-IntermediateXML.xml");
..................................
```

The XSLT file has following Code:

```
<data>
  <xsl:for-each select="//QuantitativeResponseAssay/Setup/Elements/*/Name">
    <row>
      <PLA_file_name>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vFileName"/>
      </PLA_file_name>
      <Analyst>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vAnalyst"/>
      </Analyst>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
          <Sample>Reference</Sample>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="position() = 2">
          <Sample>Sample 1</Sample>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="position() = 3">
          <Sample>Sample 2</Sample>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="position() = 4">
          <Sample>QC</Sample>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
          <Sample>Error</Sample>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <Sample_Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </Sample_Name>
      <Upper_Asymptote>
        <xsl:value-of select="//StatisticTestResults/StatisticTestResult[TestName='AdditionalTestParameterEstimateUpperAsymptote'][./InvolvedAssayElements[Name=current()]]/Value"/>
      </Upper_Asymptote>
      <Dynamic_Range>
        <xsl:value-of select="//StatisticTestResult[TestName='AdditionalTestParameterEstimateDynamicRange'][./InvolvedAssayElements[Name=current()]]/Value" />
      </Dynamic_Range>
      <Slope_Factor>
        <xsl:value-of select="//StatisticTestResult[TestName='AdditionalTestParameterEstimateSlope'][./InvolvedAssayElements[Name=current()]]/Value"/>
      </Slope_Factor>
      <Regression_pvalue>
        <xsl:if test="current() != 'Reference Standard'">
            <xsl:value-of select="//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/StatisticTestResults/StatisticTestResult[TestName='FTestRegression'][./InvolvedAssayElements[Name=current()]]/PValue" />
        </xsl:if>
      </Regression_pvalue>
      <nonparallelism_pvalue>
        <xsl:if test="current() != 'Reference Standard'">
             <xsl:value-of select="//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/StatisticTestResults/StatisticTestResult[TestName='FTestNonParallelism'][./InvolvedAssayElements[Name=current()]]/PValue" />
         </xsl:if>  
      </nonparallelism_pvalue>
      <LOF_pvalue>
        <xsl:if test="current() != 'Reference Standard'">
            <xsl:value-of select="//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/StatisticTestResults/StatisticTestResult[TestName='FTestNonLinearity'][./InvolvedAssayElements[Name=current()]]/PValue" />
        </xsl:if>
      </LOF_pvalue>
      <Potency>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/PotencyResults/PotencyResult[TestControlSampleName=current()]/RelativePotencyValue) > 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/PotencyResults/PotencyResult[TestControlSampleName=current()]/RelativePotencyValue * 100 "  />
        </xsl:if>
      </Potency>
      <!-- Column L Width_CI v -->
      <Width_CI>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/PotencyResults/PotencyResult[TestControlSampleName=current()]/PercentualRelativePotencyRange) > 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="//QuantitativeResponseAssay/AssayResults/AssayResult/PotencyResults/PotencyResult[TestControlSampleName=current()]/PercentualRelativePotencyRange * 100 " />
        </xsl:if>
      </Width_CI>
      <!-- Column M A_unrestricted v -->
      <A_unrestricted>
        <xsl:value-of select="//FullModel/FitResult/ParameterEstimate[ParameterName='A'][AssayElementName=current()]/Value" />
      </A_unrestricted>
      <!-- Column N B_unrestricted v -->
      <B_unrestricted>
        <xsl:value-of select="//FullModel/FitResult/ParameterEstimate[ParameterName='B'][AssayElementName=current()]/Value" />
      </B_unrestricted>
      <!-- Column O C_log2_unrestricted v -->
      <C_unrestricted>
        <xsl:value-of select="//FullModel/FitResult/ParameterEstimate[ParameterName='C'][AssayElementName=current()]/Value"/>
      </C_unrestricted>
      <!-- Column P D_unrestricted v -->
      <D_unrestricted>
        <xsl:value-of select="//FullModel/FitResult/ParameterEstimate[ParameterName='D'][AssayElementName=current()]/Value" />
      </D_unrestricted>
      <!-- Column Q G_unrestricted v -->
      <G_unrestricted>
        <xsl:value-of select="//FullModel/FitResult/ParameterEstimate[ParameterName='G'][AssayElementName=current()]/Value" />
      </G_unrestricted>
      <Template_ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vTemplate"/>
      </Template_ID>
      <Template_Revision>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vTemplateRevision"/>
      </Template_Revision>

    </row>
  </xsl:for-each>
</data>
```

I expect different output in each intermediate.XML file but I keep getting the fist file result in the output in intermediate file.

Comment: @dnovatchev Please help. He is great plural sight XSLT traniner

Comment: No one can say anything with certainty if not given a complete example. It may be the case that this has nothing to do with XSLT and if you want to be sure that no caching takes place, then use POST method and not GET. Or it may be the case that all the files in the directory contain the same XML document. Or ... there are too many possible reasons, without having the full picture.

Comment: It's not the solution to your problem, but there should be no need to recompile the stylesheet within the loop; you're recompiling the stylesheet every time you do a transformation, which is very inefficient.